# wireframe while everything else is solid

Tags: game-engine, wireframe

hey I'm new to the site but I am making a game in blender. there is this problem where everything is solid but this one object is stuck in wireframe while the rest is solid. I have checked the maximum draw type it is set to textured. please help.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without the file, but my first guess would be that you have the faces pointing wrong way. To fix this, in edit mode hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and select *Flip Normals*.

Answer (score 4):

Check in *edit mode* if your object actually has faces. Otherwise go to the the *material tab* and see if you have *invisible* (next to backfacing) checked, as it makes the objects look like wireframe. I added some images to show. Hope I was helpful.[image: not wireframe]
[image: wireframe]